# Erratic mouse movement on Macbook Pro trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad

I am experiencing erratic behavior of my Macbook Pro (2020) trackpad.
I can't seem to be able to precisely target anything, with the mouse constantly jumping around during movement (sometimes jumping small distances like jittering, sometimes large distances).

I used [FingerMgmt](https://github.com/jnordberg/FingerMgmt) to capture the actual inputs received from the touchpad. What I see is puzzling:

[image: Trackpad jitter in FingerMgmt]

I tried restarting the device, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

Upon unplugging the Apple Macbook charger the issues disappeared! I happened to be charging the Macbook on a train (ICE 3 in Germany) when I experienced this issue.

Further experimentation points to an issue with grounding/static charge/electric potential: When I simultaneously touch the metal macbook casing with my palm while the charger is plugged into the train, the trackpad works as expected. I guess there might be a mismatch between the potential of the train car (and in extension, me) and the internal electronics of the Macbook which are connected to the train socket, causing a current flow through the trackpad which messes up the touch detection.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what further experimentation did you carry out to reach this conclusion?

Comment: Macbook unplugged -> no issues.
Macbook plugged in, not touching case -> issues.
Macbook plugged in, touching case with the palm of the hand using the trackpad -> almost no issues.
Macbook plugged in, holding it in one hand, using the trackpad with the other -> almost no issues.

That's all, unfortunately I don't have a multimeter with me :D

Comment: same here as @ApolloLV points out

Comment: Similar, here.  Irregular mouse motion exactly while not simultaneously touching the case.  With or without charging cable, no difference.  2019 MBP.  Misbehavior started quite suddenly, over a day or two, after 3+ years of no problems, hardly ever moved from my desk.